# How many PCI express lanes does a core i7 920?

Tags: cpu, pci-express, intel-core-i7

I have been looking all over trying to find official docs on how many PCI-e lanes an intel core i7 920 has. I found documentation about the x58 chipset but I was told that PCI express lanes are usually limited by the CPU? Can any one explain this or share some official docs?

I did find this post which says that it has 36 but why cant I find that in any of intel's specs.

[For what sort of workload can a Core i7-920 be faster than a i7-860?](https://superuser.com/questions/121683/for-what-sort-of-workload-can-a-core-i7-920-be-faster-than-a-i7-860/121776#121776)

Comment: These CPUs did not have a built-in PCIe controller.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/36785/Intel-X58-Express-IO-Hub 
@DanielB They actually do on the IO hub, and the chipset can theoretically add more...

Comment: @AthomSfere I believe your miss interrupting the specifications.  Intel does two things with PCIE first it has a lane to the CPU then certain chipsets have a second lane which the motherboards handled.  I have a answer floating around here with images of the chart

Comment: The i7-920xm lists 16 max, but there is no mention of "max # of PCI lanes" in any of the i7-900 (non-suffix) series docs on Intel. Is this spec tied to socket design?

Comment: ` I was told that PCI express lanes are usually limited by the CPU`. Nope. They are not. Modern CPU's can supply PCI-e lanes, but no CPU limits the number of PCI-e lanes in a system where they are provided by several potential sources.

Comment: @Yorik - Its specified by the chipset documentation not the socket.  This has nothing to do which socket it used in a case like this.

Comment: Not sure why my question was down voted? I was told by someone at micro center that PCI express lanes are tied to the cpu and not the controller (which multiple people have explained it was wrong). Did I do something wrong in asking this question?

Comment: @ramhound: I always thought and would normally expect the chipset to define this, but I am curious why the intel documentation for some CPUs have a "max lanes" specification. Is there some circumstance where the CPU choice will affect the usable lanes? (max lanes spec under "expansion" section  http://ark.intel.com/products/43126/Intel-Core-i7-920XM-Processor-Extreme-Edition-8M-Cache-2_00-GHz )

Comment: @Yorik - Because some Intel CPUs have a PCI-E lane, the other lanes are either handled by the chipset or are external to the chipset and handled by motherboard.  I have a very good answer which contains diagrams for what I describe.  *The chipset determines what the maxium amount of lanes that are supported.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first generation of INTEL Core i3/i5/i7 technology the CPU didn't have on-chip PCIe controller, so the question is ill-formulated. Actually, the PCIe controller is provided from the I/O Hub (chipset X58), which is connected to the CPU via ["Quick Path Interconnect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) interface, similar to the older FSB -Front-Side Bus. The PCIe controller in the X58 has 4x8 PCIe interfaces, plus 1x4, for a total of 5 slots which are configurable.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I thought it might be something like that but a person at a computer store kept telling me that it was the CPU. Makes sense he was correct about the more recent CPUs but he was un aware of the older ones.

Comment: Apparently the computer store clerk is confused with memory channels. The i7-9x0 processors do have a direct (on-chip) memory controller supporting 3 (three) DDR3 memory channels, that' why the CPU pin count (socket) is 1366.

Comment: Good research makes a good answer; good answer

Comment: It is not really a research, I just happen to have a X58 LGA1366 motherboard with i7-920 as my main workstation, which I don't have much plans to change. Maybe to i7-4790 sometime later. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Nitpick: the core i7 9xx series did not have an on-chip PCIe controller, the core i7 8xx (introduced slightly later but still considered "first generation") and all i3 and i5 chips did have on-chip PCIe.

Answer (score 1):

The compatible chipset for that CPU, as per ark.intel.com is this:
http://ark.intel.com/products/36785/Intel-X58-Express-IO-Hub

It has information on PCIE revision, configuration, and max lanes.

Answer (score 0):

The i7 9xx series did not have an on-chip PCIe controller. They represent a short-lived developmental stage where the memory controller was integrated on the CPU but the PCIe controller was not.

Afaict all i7-9xx motherboards used the same chipset arrangement, an x58 "IO hub", in combination with an ICH10/ICH10R "IO controller hub".

The x58 IO hub was connected to the CPU over quickpath interconnect and gave a total of 36 PCI express 2.0 lanes. Afaict 32 of those lanes could be configured into various combinations of x16 and x8 ports while the remaining four lanes were fixed as an x4 port. The ICH10 was connected to the x58 over DMI and provided 6 PCI express 1.0 lanes (which from what I can gather were fixed as individual x1 ports) along with USB, Ethernet, SATA, LPC etc.